# Use standard macOS text editing behavior in Microsoft Word for macOS

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding, microsoft-word-2011

Is it possible to use the standard macOS text input behavior (keyboard commands) in Microsoft Word for macOS?

For example, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> in a native macOS text input field deletes the entire row, while in Word it only deletes a single word. This is the most prominent example, though there are a number of differing ways Word treats text input that drives me nuts.

Is there any such option or hack to make Word treat its text input more like the native macOS one?

Comment: Hi Simon and welcome. I improved your question's title and formatting. Hope you get your answer.